# Chrome is blocking cookies in private mode for sameSite=none and Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using identity server 4 and I have set cookiePolicy like:

in startup.cs

```
var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None,
            HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None,
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
            
        };
```

and next:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);
```

I have also react application to authorize User in ID4.
I am using Implicit Flow. When User is in normal mode everything's ok.

But when User is using private mode then the sign in window is not appear.
[sign in window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgv4c.png)

When in Google Chrome settings, Block thirty part cookies is set to Allow in private mode then everything is OK.

In case when  application is running on  localhost without https there is ok in both mode.
The problem starts when application is on server with Https certificate.

I found a lot of information but still don't know if I Can do something to allow to set cookies in private mode during authorization?

Let me know if I should provide more information ;)

Comment: I was just dealing with this issue myself (I think it was this issue). .. But using PHP. You need to set `secure` and `samesite` properties on the cookie itself - at least that's what fixed it for me.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Hmm.. I thinking that cookie Policy is setting secure attribute and sameSite = none, sameSite should be set to other value ?


Are you set this attributes in identity server or I should set this in my client somehow ?

Comment: Here's what I did in PHP:    setcookie("foo", $_POST["foo"], [
       "expires" => time() + 60 * 60 * 24,
       "path" => "/",
       "domain" => "", 
       "secure" => true,
       "httponly" => false,
       "samesite" => 'None'
      ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I set `sameSite=none`

It's mean that my IdentityServer has different domain name than my web client.

I have changed to `sameSite=Lax` *-it's mean that Identity and WebClient has the same domain name-* but I needed to change also on my IIS binding to the same domain name for Identity Server on port: 8443 Site and Web client site. (before that two domain names was different)

In this case chrome is not blocking cookies as thirty part cookie and allow set  `idsrv.external` cookie in browser in incognito mode also.

Comment: With a little formatting, the answer is great IMO :)